# Session fields values ​do not display - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

The form's session value is not shown a validation error for example

{{ object }} It is not shown.

Form

```
class EmpresaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Empresa
        fields = [
            "fantasia",
            "razao",
            "cnpj",
            "seguimento"
        ]
```

View

```
class EmpresaCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Empresa
    form_class = forms.EmpresaForm
```

Template

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.errors}}
  
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="fantasia">fantasia: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="fantasia" type="text" name="fantasia" value="{{ object.fantasia }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="razao">razao: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="razao" type="text" name="razao" value="{{ object.razao }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="cnpj">cnpj: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="cnpj" type="text" name="cnpj" value="{{ object.cnpj }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="seguimento">seguimento: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="seguimento" type="text" name="seguimento" value="{{ object.seguimento }}">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the proper spelling of the model field. It may be a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.errors}}

  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="fantasia">fantasia: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="fantasia" type="text" name="fantasia" value="{{ object.fantasia }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="razao">razao: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="razao" type="text" name="razao" value="{{ object.razao }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="cnpj">cnpj: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="cnpj" type="text" name="cnpj" value="{{ object.cnpj }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="seguimento">seguimento: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="seguimento" type="text" name="seguimento" value="{{ object.seguimento }}">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

to:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.errors}}

  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="fantasia">fantasia: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="fantasia" type="text" name="fantasia" value="{{ form.fantasia }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="razao">razao: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="razao" type="text" name="razao" value="{{ form.razao }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="cnpj">cnpj: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="cnpj" type="text" name="cnpj" value="{{ form.cnpj }}">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="seguimento">seguimento: </label>
  <input class="form-control col-sm-10" id="seguimento" type="text" name="seguimento" value="{{ form.seguimento }}">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Comment: With form.cnpj for example. A new input is shown, not just the value.

Comment: so you're using form for it. you don't need to form attribute to display the values.

Comment: or would you please edit your question and explain what you want to do and what  have you done so far.

Comment: add this line of code after every input. it may help you to see the error related to a field error.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change and why? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68932937/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).